# Error downloading previous package version in RStudio even though manual download works

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I am trying to follow the instructions from [RStudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219949047-Installing-older-versions-of-packages) to install an older version of `ggplot2` with `devtools::install_version`. However, I am getting the following error:

```
> devtools::install_version("ggplot2", version = "2.1.0", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")
Downloading package from url: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz
/usr/bin/tar: Cannot execute remote shell: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/tar: C\:\\Users\\..\RtmpmqySfr\\file75c16051e90.tar.gz: Cannot open: I/O error
/usr/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Error: Does not appear to be an R package (no DESCRIPTION)
```

My R version:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```

My RStudio version:

```
0.99.902
```

My devtools version:

```
devtools_1.12.0
```

I seem to be able to download the compressed package files directly by going to the [URL](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ggplot2/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz) found by devtools.

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: I am also getting this error when trying to do a manual install from the tar.gz file I got off that link: `devtools::install_local('.../Downloads/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz')
Error in git2r::discover_repository(path, ceiling = 0) : 
  Error in 'git2r_repository_discover': The `.git` file at '.../Downloads/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz' is malformed`

Comment: The previous error seems to be related to `there is no package called ‘scales’`. Very weird, once I had quit out of all my active `rsessions` I was able to install `scales`, then install `ggplot2` from the local download, but no luck with `install_version`.